# Marketing Cloud - Contact Builder import file is only importing one Contact record per subscriber

Tags: marketing-cloud, contactbuilder

I have been trying to import a csv file with 3 contact records, when it finish the result report is success but is only importing the last record, just the last one every time I try.

I've tried to import it with differents options every time like changing priority or status, but the result is that is always importing just the last one.

Any help will be apreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Regards,

Cristina

Comment: Is there a primary key in your data extenion?

Comment: Hi MBB, It's an import to mobile connect contacts (MobileConnect-> Manage contacts-> Import file) the wizard recognize every records and show the rows, but when i import them only the last one is imported.